# Testing rails xml rest services an I don't know where the error is on: inheritedresources or capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, acceptance-testing

I'm creating an application and i using inheritedresource controller like the one above:

```
class MyResourceController < InheritedResource::Base
  respond_to :xml
  action :create
end
```

In my cucumber test, by the way, I'm using capybara, I wrote a step definition above:

```
Given 'Sending a step definition' do
  page.driver.post(
    "/path_to_resource.xml",
<<EOF
<resource>
  <attr1>value1</attr1>
  <attr2>value2</attr2>
</resource>
EOF 
  page.status_code.should == 201
end
```

But when the test run and I checked the test logs I got:

```
Started POST "/resource.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-26 22:03:45 -0300
Processing by MyResourceController#create as XML
AREL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "resource" ("created_at", "updated_at", "attr1", "attr2") VALUES ('2011-10-27 01:03:45.763663', '2011-10-27 01:03:45.763663', NULL, NULL)
Completed 201 Created in 96ms (Views: 32.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Unfortunally, I'm try to figure out this since last week with no success. So my question is: Am I calling capybara post with wrong parameters or posting wrong xml to controller?